# select list is not in group by clause contains nonaggregated column

Tags: php, sql

I am trying this SQL query,

```
SELECT `id`, `amount`, `symbol`, `uid`, SUM(amount) as total
FROM `faucet_summary`
WHERE `uid` = '27'
GROUP BY `symbol`
```

and the problem I am having is with `group by symbol`

My table looks like the following;

[image]

The error I am getting is

> #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '{DB}.faucet_summary.id' which is not
> functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Is there something I'm missing?

My desired result would be;

```
20    CSC   27
1000  SHIB  27
```

Comment: `Full group by` is apparently enforced, add all 3 columns to the `GROUP BY`. See [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by), and this [more detailed info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: A symbol can have different id values. Which one do you want? (Note that your desired result contains no id column, so why do you select it?)